# setpgid for Child Zombie Process Gives ESRCH instead of EACCES?

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

According to the man `setpgid(2)` page,

> EACCES An attempt was made to change the process group ID of one of the children of the calling process and the child had already performed an execve(2) (setpgid(), setpgrp()).
>
> ESRCH  For getpgid(): pid does not match any process.  For setpgid(): pid is not the calling process and not a child of the calling process.

The errno should be `EACCES` according to the description. But why do I get `ESRCH` instead?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

void print_errno() {
  if (errno == EACCES) printf("errno: EACCES\n");
  else if (errno == EPERM) printf("errno: EPERM\n");
  else if (errno == ESRCH) printf("errno: ESRCH\n");
}

#define CHECK(syscall, msg) do {                    \
    if ((syscall) == -1) {                          \
      print_errno();                                \
      perror(msg);                                  \
      _exit(1);                                     \
    }                                               \
  } while(0)

int main () {
  int ls_pid;
  char *ls_argv[] = { "ls", NULL };

  CHECK(ls_pid = fork(), "fork error");
  if (!ls_pid) {
    CHECK(execvp(ls_argv[0], ls_argv), "execvp error");
  } else {
    sleep(2);
    CHECK(setpgid(ls_pid, ls_pid), "setpgid error");
    CHECK(wait(NULL), "wait error");

    printf("Finish\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `strerror`?

Comment: Trying to change the process group of an already died process (which a zombie is) is of no interest so `ESRCH` seems a very reasonable error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification of `setpgid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgid.html) does not say what error is to be returned by `setpgid` when the pid argument refers to a *zombie* child of the calling process, whether or not it called `execve`.  Thus, this is not technically a bug.

`ESRCH` makes sense if you consider that zombies aren't really processes anymore; they're just the data that needs to stick around until someone gets around to calling `wait`.  For instance, it would make a lot of sense for `kill` to fail with `ESRCH` when applied to a zombie.

I'd like to close with some observations on how this is actually implemented, but, alas,  I looked at the source code for `setpgid` in Linux and could not figure out what it would return for this case, because Linux's namespace support has turned many process-related syscalls into horrible mazes of spaghetti.  So then I tried to look at FreeBSD instead and I couldn't even find the relevant part of the source code, because the file-level organization of the FreeBSD kernel is incomprehensible.  So you're going to have to do without, sorry.

Comment: Looks like in Linux zombies are removed from their thread group and `setpgid` returns `ESRCH` if caller and process to move aren't in the same thread group. That is reasonable to consider a zombie as absent from almost all kernel list.

Comment: Actually I tried the same piece of code on different computers. Some return `EACCES` while others return `ESRCH`.